Equal distribution of light sources in a room (title probably worded wrong, please correct if needed)
English isn't my first language, and mathematics (in which I'm also bad at) has highly technical terms, so feel free to correct what I name and do wrong when asking this.
I've forgotten anything past fractions, so you are dealing with a math idiot here.
And I also don't know how I should tag this.
Intro:
It is for games. Like Minecraft-y (that is including similar ones). I am sick of to just slap my light sources wherever and want to plunk them down at equal distance to each other and with the same distance to the wall/edge.
Edit: Horizontal and vertical only. I don't care about diagonals.
And trial and error just takes too long, so I want to calculate the distances.
The rules:

All light sources should have the same distance vertically and horizontally to each other. * And also no source shouldn't be closer to a wall than to another source.
No light source should be closer to another than 3 (aka. two blank spaces in between).
No light source should be further apart than 10 (aka. 9 blank spaces in between).

Examples found by trial and error:

A 5 by 5 room is the smallest possible with a single source in the middle (has 2 blank spaces to all sides)
if I extend that pattern, the next room size is: 8 by x (x>5). That room would have 4 light sources. All of them 3 spaces from the wall and from each other.

Like that (full room): (A block without light; ° block with light)



AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
AA°AA°AA
AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
AA°AA°AA
AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAA


The same as table:




0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8




1
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A


2
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A


3
A
A
°
A
A
°
A
A


4
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A


5
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A


6
A
A
°
A
A
°
A
A


7
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A


8
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A



Things I found out so far:

5 by 5 is the smallest room, that can fulfil all rules.
A room with a side length of 10 doesn't work/can't fulfil the rules.
An 11 by 11 room has 3 solutions. (Every 3, every 4, and a single in the middle= every 6.)

What do I need it for now?

I have a room that is 99 by 59 blocks.
I can extend or shrink the room up to 5 blocks in 3 of the 4 directions. (Min 89 by 55 [see below]; max 109 by 63)
The room has to stay an odd number of blocks in both axis.


It sounds like your rule "equidistant from walls and other sources" must be limited by "in the vertical and horizontal directions only, nearest only" since a diagonal distance would not match and there are too many combinations otherwise.

According to the rules as I understand them, you just need to add one to each dimension length and find a common factor and use that to make your light grid.  So $89\cdot 55$ doesn't work because the common factor after the increase is $2$.  Bumping up to $89\cdot 59$ should work so you would have lights every $6$ squares on a grid.  Or $95\cdot 55$ could also work for lights on every $8$ squares.

Sorry, I didn't made it clear that the diagonals are excluded. I only mean vertical and horizontal.

Note that the distance of a light source from a wall should be half the distance between light sources.

@Moti what is your reasoning for offering an alternate rule vs. the one given in the question?

The intensity of the light is a function of the distance from the source. Between based on this I would even say that the distance from the wall should be a 1/4 of the distance between two light source - in the middle between two light source you get light from both sources so if you have only one light source half the distance of the middle will get same intensity assuming farther sources do not have an impact (which is not true)

@Moti. I don't care about that. In this case, it is open to the outside, so light shines in. And if it is really too dark, I illuminate the wall.
